# PuGXMultiUserBundle , multiple registration forms for same class users

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I want to provide different login/register pages/forms for my users, but the users are the same class. I don't want to populate the database with additional tables.

```
pugx_multi_user:
  users:
    medics:
        entity:
          class: MedAppBundle\Entity\User
        registration:
          form:
            type: MedAppBundle\Form\MedicRegistrationType
            name: app_medics_registration
            validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
          template: MedAppBundle:Registration:registerMedic.html.twig
        profile:
          form:
            type: MedAppBundle\Form\ProfileType
            validation_groups:  [Profile, Default]
    patients:
        entity:
          class: MedAppBundle\Entity\User
        registration:
          form:
            type: MedAppBundle\Form\PatientsRegistrationType
          template: MedAppBundle:Registration:registerPacient.html.twig
        profile:
          form:
            type: MedAppBundle\Form\ProfileType
            validation_groups:  [Profile, Default]
```

And here is the registration class :

```
class RegController extends Controller
{


    public function registerPatientAction()
    {
        return $this->container
            ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
            ->register('MedAppBundle\Entity\User');
    }


    public function registerMedicAction()
    {
        return $this->container
            ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
            ->register('MedAppBundle\Entity\User');
    }
```

Unfortunately the forms all end up as the last type of user, namely pacients. This configuration doesn't work mainly because `UserDiscriminator` takes values by class instead of user type names.

Is there any kind of configuration that helps or does anyone have any kind of idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `PuGXMultiUserBundle` for your needs it does not make sense.

Just use the `FOSUserBundle` and create additional routes for your registration/login templates and set them all on the appropriate FOSUser-Controller-Action.

So all register forms to the FOS register-action and all login forms to the fos-register action (you can lookup which actions FOS is using for login/register inside the FOS-routing files)

Comment: This is the correct answer and what I need to do. Thanks a lot!